# Add views in UIStackView programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, uistackview

I'm trying to add views in UIStackView programmatically. 
For now My code is:

```
UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc]init];
view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[view1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];

UIView *view2 =  [[UIView alloc]init];
view2.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
[view2 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 100, 100)];

[self.stack1 addArrangedSubview:view1];
[self.stack1 addArrangedSubview:view2];
```

When i deploy the app, there is only 1 view and it is with black colour.(view1 get the parameters for view2 too)

Comment: You sanity checked your outlet? Did you log the subviews at runtime?

Comment: Use `addArrangedSubview:`, not `addSubview:`

Answer (score 292, accepted):

Stack views use intrinsic content size, so use layout constraints to define the dimensions of the views.

There is an easy way to add constraints quickly (example):

```
[view1.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:100].active = true;
```

**Complete Code:**

```
- (void) setup {

    //View 1
    UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc] init];
    view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [view1.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:100].active = true;
    [view1.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:120].active = true;


    //View 2
    UIView *view2 = [[UIView alloc] init];
    view2.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [view2.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:100].active = true;
    [view2.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:70].active = true;

    //View 3
    UIView *view3 = [[UIView alloc] init];
    view3.backgroundColor = [UIColor magentaColor];
    [view3.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:100].active = true;
    [view3.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:180].active = true;

    //Stack View
    UIStackView *stackView = [[UIStackView alloc] init];

    stackView.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical;
    stackView.distribution = UIStackViewDistributionEqualSpacing;
    stackView.alignment = UIStackViewAlignmentCenter;
    stackView.spacing = 30;


    [stackView addArrangedSubview:view1];
    [stackView addArrangedSubview:view2];
    [stackView addArrangedSubview:view3];

    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    [self.view addSubview:stackView];


    //Layout for Stack View
    [stackView.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.centerXAnchor].active = true;
    [stackView.centerYAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.centerYAnchor].active = true;
}
```

**Note:** This was tested on iOS 9

[image: UIStackView Equal Spacing (centered)]

Comment: The point of using stack views is that they hide the details of constraint management from the developer. As you pointed out, this relies on the subviews having an intrinsic content size, which default `UIViews` do not. If the original poster had used `UILabel` instances instead of `UIView`, his code would have worked as he expected. I added an example that demonstrates this below.

Comment: when i do this "[view1.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:100].active = true;" im getting error on ios 8.It's working only on ios 9.I know that uistackview is for ios 9+ but how can i set heightAncor constraint for ios 8

Comment: My StackView is added using storyboard. At runtime I am adding several UIViews(contain other subviews) to stackView. After loading data all views inside stackView are having same height, they are not getting resized according to content. @user1046037

Comment: Do you have constraints set for those individual views so that their size would vary based on the content ?

Comment: This is the best & optimal way to manage views with equal widths or heights

Comment: Swift 5 version: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58827722/2273338

Answer (score 202):

**Swift 5.0**

```
//Image View
let imageView = UIImageView()
imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120.0).isActive = true
imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120.0).isActive = true
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "buttonFollowCheckGreen")

//Text Label
let textLabel = UILabel()
textLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
textLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: self.view.frame.width).isActive = true
textLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20.0).isActive = true
textLabel.text  = "Hi World"
textLabel.textAlignment = .center

//Stack View
let stackView   = UIStackView()
stackView.axis  = NSLayoutConstraint.Axis.vertical
stackView.distribution  = UIStackView.Distribution.equalSpacing
stackView.alignment = UIStackView.Alignment.center
stackView.spacing   = 16.0

stackView.addArrangedSubview(imageView)
stackView.addArrangedSubview(textLabel)
stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

self.view.addSubview(stackView)

//Constraints
stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
stackView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

Based on @user1046037 answer.

Comment: Starting **iOS 8**, it's possible to activate the constraints in batch using `activate(_:)`, and it's typically more efficient to do it this way https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutconstraint/1526955-activate

Comment: Swift 5 version: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58827722/2273338

Answer (score 27):

**In Swift 4.2**

```swift
let redView = UIView()
redView.backgroundColor = .red

let blueView = UIView()
blueView.backgroundColor = .blue

let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [redView, blueView])
stackView.axis = .vertical
stackView.distribution = .fillEqually

view.addSubview(stackView)

// stackView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)

// autolayout constraint
stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
    stackView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor),
    stackView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor),
    stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200)
])
```

Answer (score 22):

`UIStackView` uses constraints internally to position its arranged subviews. Exactly what constraints are created depends on how the stack view itself is configured. By default, a stack view will create constraints that lay out its arranged subviews in a horizontal line, pinning the leading and trailing views to its own leading and trailing edges. So your code would produce a layout that looks like this:

```
|[view1][view2]|
```

The space that is allocated to each subview is determined by a number of factors including the subview's intrinsic content size and it's compression resistance and content hugging priorities. By default, `UIView` instances don't define an intrinsic content size. This is something that is generally provided by a subclass, such as `UILabel` or `UIButton`.

Since the content compression resistance and content hugging priorities of two new `UIView` instances will be the same, and neither view provides an intrinsic content size, the layout engine must make its best guess as to what size should be allocated to each view. In your case, it is assigning the first view 100% of the available space, and nothing to the second view.

If you modify your code to use `UILabel` instances instead, you will get better results:

```
UILabel *label1 = [UILabel new];
label1.text = @"Label 1";
label1.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

UILabel *label2 = [UILabel new];
label2.text = @"Label 2";
label2.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

[self.stack1 addArrangedSubview:label1];
[self.stack1 addArrangedSubview:label2];
```

Note that it is not necessary to explictly create any constraints yourself. This is the main benefit of using `UIStackView` - it hides the (often ugly) details of constraint management from the developer.

Comment: I have the same problem that this works for Labels, but not for TextFields (or Views, for that matter). Also all tutorials I find use Labels, Images or Buttons. Does this mean that for anything different than these UI elements, we cannot use this method?

Comment: @physicalattraction The views you add to a stack view must have an intrinsic content size. As I recall, the intrinsic size of a text field is based on the content of the field (which is odd). Instances of `UIView` itself do not have an intrinsic size. You may need to apply additional constraints to these views so the stack view knows how big to make them.

Comment: Makes sense, so I am trying it. Now I have built a View in a xib with a textfield, which I give an explicit height constraint of 30 pixels. I furthermore make the following two constraints: `MyTextField.top = top+20` and `bottom = MyTextField.bottom+20`. I would expect this would give my view an intrinsic height of 70, but instead it complains about conflicting constraints. Do you know what is going on here? It is this View that I want to place inside my UIStackView.

Comment: I think I know what the problem is. A stack view automatically pins its final arranged subview to its bottom edge. So the stack view is trying to make your container view the same size as itself. However, you have told this view that it must be 70 pixels tall, which creates a conflict. Try creating an additional empty view immediately after your container view and give it a vertical content hugging priority of 0. Give your container view a vertical content hugging priority of 1000. That will cause the empty view to stretch to fill the empty space in the stack view.

Comment: I'm assuming you are using a vertical stack view by the way. You may also want to check out this article I wrote about stack views: https://dzone.com/articles/building-responsive-ios-applications-using-markup

Comment: Thanks, I will check out this article later this week. The complaints about the conflicting constraints were in UIView only, without even placing them in a StackView. I noticed that I could at least calm down Xcode by lowering the priority of two of the three constraints, but I'm still struggling to make it right.

Answer (score 10):

You have to set you distribution type.
In your code, juste add:

```
self.stack1.distribution = UIStackViewDistributionFillEqually;
```

Or you can set the distribution directly in your interface builder.
For example:

[image]

Hope that helps ;)
Lapinou.

Answer (score 10):

Following two lines fixed my issue

```
view.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(50).active = true;
view.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(350).active = true;
```

Swift version -

```
var DynamicView=UIView(frame: CGRectMake(100, 200, 100, 100))
DynamicView.backgroundColor=UIColor.greenColor()
DynamicView.layer.cornerRadius=25
DynamicView.layer.borderWidth=2
self.view.addSubview(DynamicView)
DynamicView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(50).active = true;
DynamicView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(350).active = true;

var DynamicView2=UIView(frame: CGRectMake(100, 310, 100, 100))
DynamicView2.backgroundColor=UIColor.greenColor()
DynamicView2.layer.cornerRadius=25
DynamicView2.layer.borderWidth=2
self.view.addSubview(DynamicView2)
DynamicView2.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(50).active = true;
DynamicView2.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(350).active = true;

var DynamicView3:UIView=UIView(frame: CGRectMake(10, 420, 355, 100))
DynamicView3.backgroundColor=UIColor.greenColor()
DynamicView3.layer.cornerRadius=25
DynamicView3.layer.borderWidth=2
self.view.addSubview(DynamicView3)

let yourLabel:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(110, 10, 200, 20))
yourLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
//yourLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
yourLabel.text = "mylabel text"
DynamicView3.addSubview(yourLabel)
DynamicView3.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(50).active = true;
DynamicView3.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(350).active = true;

let stackView   = UIStackView()
stackView.axis  = UILayoutConstraintAxis.Vertical
stackView.distribution  = UIStackViewDistribution.EqualSpacing
stackView.alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.Center
stackView.spacing   = 30

stackView.addArrangedSubview(DynamicView)
stackView.addArrangedSubview(DynamicView2)
stackView.addArrangedSubview(DynamicView3)

stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

self.view.addSubview(stackView)

//Constraints
stackView.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.centerXAnchor).active = true
stackView.centerYAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.centerYAnchor).active = true
```

Answer (score 8):

For the accepted answer when you try to hide any view inside stack view, the constraint works not correct.

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x618000086e50 UIView:0x7fc11c4051c0.height == 120   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x610000084fb0 'UISV-hiding' UIView:0x7fc11c4051c0.height == 0   (active)>"
)
```

**Reason** is when hide the `view` in `stackView` it will set the height to 0 to animate it.

**Solution** change the constraint `priority` as below.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let stackView = UIStackView()
    let a = UIView()
    let b = UIView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        a.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        a.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
        let aHeight = a.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120)
        aHeight.isActive = true
        aHeight.priority = 999

        let bHeight = b.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120)
        bHeight.isActive = true
        bHeight.priority = 999
        b.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        b.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true

        view.addSubview(stackView)
        stackView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(a)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(b)
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.distribution = .equalSpacing
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // Just add a button in xib file or storyboard and add connect this action.
    @IBAction func test(_ sender: Any) {
        a.isHidden = !a.isHidden
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
    //Image View
    let imageView               = UIImageView()
    imageView.backgroundColor   = UIColor.blueColor()
    imageView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(120.0).active = true
    imageView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(120.0).active = true
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "buttonFollowCheckGreen")

    //Text Label
    let textLabel               = UILabel()
    textLabel.backgroundColor   = UIColor.greenColor()
    textLabel.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(self.view.frame.width).active = true
    textLabel.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(20.0).active = true
    textLabel.text  = "Hi World"
    textLabel.textAlignment = .Center


    //Third View
    let thirdView               = UIImageView()
    thirdView.backgroundColor   = UIColor.magentaColor()
    thirdView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(120.0).active = true
    thirdView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(120.0).active = true
    thirdView.image = UIImage(named: "buttonFollowMagenta")


    //Stack View
    let stackView   = UIStackView()
    stackView.axis  = UILayoutConstraintAxis.Vertical
    stackView.distribution  = UIStackViewDistribution.EqualSpacing
    stackView.alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.Center
    stackView.spacing   = 16.0

    stackView.addArrangedSubview(imageView)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(textLabel)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(thirdView)
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

    self.view.addSubview(stackView)

    //Constraints
    stackView.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.centerXAnchor).active = true
    stackView.centerYAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.centerYAnchor).active = true
```

Improved on the answer by @Oleg Popov

Answer (score 5):

In my case the thing that was messing with I would expect was that I was missing this line:

```
stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
```

After that no need to set constraints to my arranged subviews whatsoever, the stackview is taking care of that.

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 5** version of [Oleg Popov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32675332/2273338), which is based on [user1046037's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31577312/2273338)

```
//Image View
let imageView = UIImageView()
imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120.0).isActive = true
imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120.0).isActive = true
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "buttonFollowCheckGreen")

//Text Label
let textLabel = UILabel()
textLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
textLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: self.view.frame.width).isActive = true
textLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20.0).isActive = true
textLabel.text  = "Hi World"
textLabel.textAlignment = .center

//Stack View
let stackView   = UIStackView()
stackView.axis  = NSLayoutConstraint.Axis.vertical
stackView.distribution  = UIStackView.Distribution.equalSpacing
stackView.alignment = UIStackView.Alignment.center
stackView.spacing   = 16.0

stackView.addArrangedSubview(imageView)
stackView.addArrangedSubview(textLabel)
stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

self.view.addSubview(stackView)

//Constraints
stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
stackView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have many `UIView`s to add, you can use the following extension where you pass an array of `UIView`s where it will add them into the `UIStackView` by order

```
extension UIStackView {
    func addArrangedSubviews(_ subviews: [UIView]) {
        subviews.forEach{ self.addArrangedSubview($0) }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have want to add UIView at specific position, use this

```
yourStackView.insertArrangedSubview(yourView, at: index)
```

Answer (score 1):

I just came across very similar problem. Just like mentioned before the stack view's dimensions depend one intrinsic content size of the arranged subviews. Here is my solution in Swift 2.x and following view structure:

view - UIView

customView - CustomView:UIView

stackView - UISTackView

arranged subviews - custom UIView subclasses

```
    //: [Previous](@previous)

import Foundation
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

/**Container for stack view*/
class CustomView:UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }


    init(){
        super.init(frame: CGRectZero)

    }

}

/**Custom Subclass*/
class CustomDrawing:UIView{
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()

    }

    func setup(){
       // self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        print("setup \(frame)")
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, 0, 0)
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, CGRectGetWidth(bounds), CGRectGetHeight(bounds))
        CGContextStrokePath(ctx)

        print("DrawRect")

    }
}



//: [Next](@next)
let stackView = UIStackView()
stackView.distribution = .FillProportionally
stackView.alignment = .Center
stackView.axis = .Horizontal
stackView.spacing = 10


//container view
let view = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,320,640))
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
//now custom view

let customView = CustomView()

view.addSubview(customView)

customView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
customView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(220).active = true
customView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(60).active = true
customView.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.centerXAnchor).active = true
customView.centerYAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.centerYAnchor).active = true
customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()

//add a stack view
customView.addSubview(stackView)
stackView.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(customView.centerXAnchor).active = true
stackView.centerYAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(customView.centerYAnchor).active = true
stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false


let c1 = CustomDrawing()
c1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
c1.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
c1.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(30).active = true
c1.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(30).active = true

let c2 = CustomDrawing()
c2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
c2.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
c2.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(30).active = true
c2.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(30).active = true


stackView.addArrangedSubview(c1)
stackView.addArrangedSubview(c2)


XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = view
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of coding all the constrains you could use a subclass that handles `.intrinsicContentSize` of `UIView` class in a simpler way.
This solution improves also **Interface Builder** a little in a way to support with "*intrinsicWidth*" and "*intrinsicHeight*" of views. While you could extend UIView's and have those properties available on all UIViews in **IB** its cleaner to subclass.

```
// IntrinsicView.h
@import UIKit

IB_DESIGNABLE
@interface IntrinsicView : UIView
-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)rect;
@property IBInspectable CGSize intrinsic;
@end
```

```
// IntrinsicView.m
#import "IntrinsicView.h"

@implementation IntrinsicView {
    CGSize _intrinsic;
}
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    _intrinsic = frame.size;
    if ( !(self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) ) return nil;
    // your stuff here..
    return self;
}
-(CGSize)intrinsicContentSize {
    return _intrinsic;
}
-(void)prepareForInterfaceBuilder {
    self.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y, _intrinsic.width,_intrinsic.height);
}
@end
```

Which means you can just allocate those IntrinsicView's and the `self.frame.size` is taken as `intrinsicContentSize`. That way it does not disturb the normal layout and you dont need to set constraint relations that don't even apply in full with `UIStackViews`

```
#import "IntrinsicView.h"

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    UIStackView *column = [[UIStackView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    column.spacing = 2;
    column.alignment = UIStackViewAlignmentFill;
    column.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical; //Up-Down
    column.distribution = UIStackViewDistributionFillEqually;
    
    for (int row=0; row<5; row++) {
        //..frame:(CGRect) defines here proportions and
        //relation to axis of StackView
        IntrinsicView *intrinsicView = [[IntrinsicView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30.0, 30.0)];
        
        [column addArrangedSubview:intrinsicView];
    }
    [self.view addSubview:column];
}
```

now you can go crazy with UIStackView's
[image]

or in **swift** + encoding, decoding, IB support, Objective-C support

```
@IBDesignable @objc class IntrinsicView : UIView {
    @IBInspectable var intrinsic : CGSize
    @objc override init(frame: CGRect) {
        intrinsic = frame.size
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        intrinsic = coder.decodeCGSize(forKey: "intrinsic")
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
    override func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encode(intrinsic, forKey: "intrinsic")
        super.encode(with: coder)
    }
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return intrinsic
    }
    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.origin.x, y: self.frame.origin.y, width: intrinsic.width, height: intrinsic.height)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is really not recommended to set a height constraint... If you can, never, never, never set a height! You need to check all the constraints of the views inside your UIStackView and be sure that there is constraints for bottom, top, leading and trailing. Someone said to me: it is like a guy pushing on walls. If he don't push on 4 sides, one of the wall will fall on him.

Answer (score -1):

```
func configureHorizontalView(){
    containerView.addSubview(horizontalStackView)
    _ = horizontalStackView.anchor(top: secondCurrencyTextField.bottomAnchor, 
                                   left: containerView.leftAnchor, 
                                   bottom: nil, 
                                   right: containerView.rightAnchor, 
                                   topConstant: 40, 
                                   leftConstant: 30, 
                                   bottomConstant: 0, 
                                   rightConstant: 30, 
                                   widthConstant: 0, 
                                   heightConstant: 65)
}

func configureFirstDropDownlabel(){
    //add a view to stackView with addArrangedSubview() 
    horizontalStackView.addArrangedSubview(firstDropDownlabel)
    _ = firstDropDownlabel.anchor(top: horizontalStackView.bottomAnchor, 
                                  left: horizontalStackView.leftAnchor, 
                                  bottom: nil, right: nil, 
                                  topConstant: 40, 
                                  leftConstant: 30, 
                                  bottomConstant: 0, 
                                  rightConstant: 0, 
                                  widthConstant: 0, 
                                  heightConstant: 0)
    firstDropDownlabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 130).isActive = true
    firstDropDownlabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 65).isActive = true
}
```

Comment: Please consider to add some feedback of what the code does to make it easier to understand.

Comment: Please include some minimum explanation to allow us to work on your issue

Answer (score -2):

Try below code:

```
UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc]init];
view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[view1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];

UIView *view2 =  [[UIView alloc]init];
view2.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
[view2 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 100, 100)];

NSArray *subView = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:view1,view2, nil];

[self.stack1 initWithArrangedSubviews:subView];
```