# how to set multiple UIview on centre in horizontal with auto resizing

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

i have one view and set multiple subviews on the view, my subviews is dynamically created, i want all subview in centre and auto resizable, so how can do it.

[image]

```
for(i=1; i<answer.characters.count; i++) {

             ansview = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(viewwidth-5, 10, 30, 30))

            ansview.layer.cornerRadius = 0.2 * btn.bounds.size.width
            ansview.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
            ansview.tag = i;

            viewAnswer.addSubview(ansview)

            viewwidth = viewwidth + 35
}
```

this type of output generated to this code, so how can do it i am new in swift.
thanks...

Comment: Have you considered UIStackView?  You can [programmatically add views to it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30728062/4151918).

Answer (score 1):

add one condition to set frame of view

```
if(i == 1)
  {   
     ansview = UIView(frame: CGRectMake((viewAnswer.frame.size.width/2) - (CGFloat(answer.characters.count)/2 * 35), 10, 30, 30))
  }
    else
   {
     ansview = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(viewwidth-5, 10, 30, 30))
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Only with constraints It can't be achieved. Create virtual view in either sides of view collection and make widths equal

[image]

Accepted answer of this question might help you [Evenly space multiple views within a container view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13075415/evenly-space-multiple-views-within-a-container-view)