# Creating iOS UIStackView programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, uistackview

How to create UIStackview programmatically?
Is there any way to modify stack count dynamically?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30728062/add-views-in-uistackview-programmatically

Comment: Have a look here on how to create the stackview: https://riptutorial.com/ios/example/4534/create-a-horizontal-stack-view-programmatically For modifying the stackview dynamically i suggest you use the UIView.isHidden property, then you dont have to actually remove the view from the stackview.
Have a look here on how to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46326302/uistackview-hide-view-animation

Answer (score -3):

please read a tutorial from this: http://www.appcoda.com/stack-views-intro/

Comment: The question is programmatically, not using interface designer.