# Animating Nested UIStackViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistackview

I'm working on a app with a combined login/signup screen. When the user taps "Sign up" at the bottom, a birth date field and a terms of service checkbox appear below the email and password field so the user can sign up. The problem I'm having is that when I animate the stack view containing the birth date text field and terms of service view, they animate from the top of the email text field even though they are located below the password text field.

[image]

Code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:animated == YES ? 0.4 : 0 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
        self.signUpFieldsStackView.hidden = NO;
        self.signUpFieldsStackView.alpha = 1;
    } completion:nil];
```

These controls are nested inside `UIStackView`'s like so:

- `UIStackView`

  - `UIStackView`

    - `UIStackView` (`loginFieldsStackView`)

      - email text field
      - password text field
    - `UIStackView` (`signUpFieldsStackView`)

      - birth date text field
      - terms of service view
  - Login button
  - `UIView`

    - "Don't have an account" label
    - "Sign up" button

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/q/46326302/5442445?

Comment: @beyowulf - I hadn't seen that. I'll try it out now. thanks

Comment: @beyowulf - it works! thanks!