# UIStackView, hiding subview with resizing animation

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

I have seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46326302/uistackview-hide-view-animation) very smooth animation of hiding/showing subview in `UIStackView`.

I try to reproduce it in my own application but I have meet a problem.

[image]

View that is hidden during animation proces does not resize. It just wait until animation finish and then disappear. Opposite to `clear button` from above linked example.

My code:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5,
               delay: 0.0,
               usingSpringWithDamping: 0.9,
               initialSpringVelocity: 1,
               options: [],
               animations: {
                    self.acceptDeclineBar.isHidden = !newState
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                },
               completion: nil)
```

**Question**

Is `UIStackView` give resizing animation on hide/show for free or do I need implement it for myself using height constraint for example?

Comment: Your view (self.acceptDeclineBar) will hide when the animation completes. try to hide before the animation. 
self.acceptDeclineBar.isHidden = !newState
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5,
               delay: 0.0,
               usingSpringWithDamping: 0.9,
               initialSpringVelocity: 1,
               options: [],
               animations: {
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                },
               completion: nil)

Comment: Looks better, but `acceptDeclineBar` still does not resize like `clear button` from my goal.

Comment: check with the removing bottom constraint of buttons super view.

Answer (score 1):

Your view `(self.acceptDeclineBar)` will hide when the animation completes. try to hide before the animation.

```
self.acceptDeclineBar.isHidden = !newState

 UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3){ [weak self]
                    self?.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

or instead of hiding you can use Height Constraint

```
acceptDeclineBarHeightConstraint.constant = newState ? 60 (whatever Visbale size) : 0 (Hide)
 UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3){ [weak self]
                    self?.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: changing `HeightConstraint` is obvious idea, I thought `UIStackView` gives my resizing for free :/

Comment: check with the removing bottom constraint of buttons super view.