# Horizontal collection view with stack view inside a stack view hide inner stack view on reload with animation

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, custom-cell

Hi I have a collection view which has collectionview cell with a outer stack view containing a uibutton and another stack view inside it.

It is a collapsible collection view as I click the uibutton in the cell, it must hide the inner stack view with animation. How to do this

```
Collection view cell
   Content view
     Stack view
        Uibutton
        Stack view
```

I want to hide the inner stack view with animation on selecting the UI button

```
Cell Code

func setupUI(_ hidden: Bool, filter: Filter) {

    self.filter = filter

    UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
        expandableStackView.isHidden = hidden ? false : true
        self.filterTitleButton.setTitle(filter.filterTitle, for: .normal)
    }
}
```

In Controller cell for row i will call this setUpUI function

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: @Anbu I updated the question please check. Hide is working fine and when I give without animation. But I want to unhide the stack view like it should slide to right on selected and go behind the button on unselected with slide left animation

Answer (score 0):

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 3,
                   delay: 0.0,
                   usingSpringWithDamping: 0.9,
                   initialSpringVelocity: 1,
                   options: [],
                   animations: {
                        innerStackView.hidden = true
                        stackView.layoutIfNeeded()
                    },
                   completion: nil)
```

also here is extension you can use 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53517910/1780632