# Weird animation when hiding and unhiding button in UIStackView

Tags: swift, constraints

I'm trying to animate in and out a button in a stack view, when one is pressed. When hiding the camera button, the animation looks fine, but when unhiding it slides in from the left which looks odd.

[image: Link to GIF since StackOverflow won't let me embed]

Code below:

```
@IBAction func scanButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    
    
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) { [self] in
        if cameraButton.alpha == 0{
            cameraButton.alpha = 1
        }else{
            cameraButton.alpha = 0
        }
    }
    
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) { [self] in
        cameraButton.isHidden.toggle()
        
    }
    
}
```

I've tried to fix it by using constraints instead of a stack but to no avail. If anyone could help it would be much appreciated. (Please ignore how awful the if/else statement is)

Comment: That completion handler loops suspicious

Comment: Also if you're just animating the alpha to 0, no need to set `isHidden`. The button is automatically made so that it can't be pressed

Comment: Btw for images you need to add `!` in front

Comment: Can you try to call stackView.layoutIfNeeded() after isHidden.toggle()

Comment: @aheze they are not using images, the UIButtons are using a linear gradient, but I think that is unrelated since it happens without the gradients. Removing isHidden from it means that the button no longer animates movement at all

Comment: Here's more context for @ibrahimyilmaz: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46326302/uistackview-hide-view-animation?rq=1

Comment: @cheesegrater I meant for the image embed in your post

Comment: @aheze ah I see, it says I need 10 reputation to embed :/

Comment: @cheesegrater you have enough reputation now :)

Comment: Also, it's better to put both codes inside the same animate block.

Comment: @ibrahimyilmaz thanks so much... it fixed my issue.. I feel so stupid

Comment: It's normal because it's an unexpected behavior. I had this idea because I faced the same before. Happy for you. :)

Answer (score 3):

Cheers to @Ibrahimyilmaz. The solution involved just adding `stackView.layoutIfNeeded()`
after `isHidden.toggle()`

[image]

[Some more infomation on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46326302/uistackview-hide-view-animation?rq=1) courtesy of @aheze