# Why does animated view start from wrong position?

Tags: swift, autolayout, uiviewanimation

I'm using auto layout to animate the elements in a stack view. I've set the leading and trailing constraints, both with a priority of 1000 (required). However, as you can see from the animated gif, the stack view is initially attached on the left but not on the right.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.125, delay: animationDelay, options: [.curveEaseOut],
               animations: {
                   someView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
                   someView.alpha = 1
                   someView.isHidden = false
               }, completion: nil)
```

[image: View doesn't appear to be initially constrained to the right side]

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46326302/uistackview-hide-view-animation

Comment: AFAIK `UIStackView` animates `isHidden`. So maybe that's why you see that weird animation.