# Whats is wrong with UIStackView layout?

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

UIKit is making me feel like extremely frustrated. I have this little piece of code in Xcode playgrounds:

```
    let views = [UIView(), UIView(), UIView()]

for view in views {
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    view.bounds.size = CGSize(width: 40, height: 40)
}

let stack = UIStackView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 40))
stack.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

stack.addArrangedSubview(views[0])
stack.addArrangedSubview(views[1])
stack.addArrangedSubview(views[2])

stack.axis = .Horizontal
stack.distribution = .Fill
stack.alignment = .Center
stack.spacing = 5
```

But no matter which distribution strategy I chose, I always end up with this.My expectation is to see three squares spread evenly in the stack.
Not all of them on top of each other.

[image]

It seem auto layout in stack view is not laying items out properly.

But why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30728062/add-views-in-uistackview-programmatically

Comment: It is not duplicate guys, OP is working on Xcode Playground.

Comment: were you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: Yes. Completely counterintuitively, you MUST set up some autolayout constraints on the members views. I consider this incrediblely stupid design. Apple is presenting the stack view as a solution being one abstraction layer ABOVE autolayout. Why do I still need autolayout? I shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it working:

```
import UIKit

func getRandomColor() -> UIColor {
    let randomRed:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())
    let randomGreen:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())
    let randomBlue:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())
    return UIColor(red: randomRed, green: randomGreen, blue: randomBlue, alpha: 1.0)
}

let standardFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 40)
let rootView = UIView(frame: standardFrame)
rootView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

let views = [UIView(), UIView(), UIView()]

for view in views {
    view.backgroundColor = getRandomColor()
    view.bounds.size = CGSize(width: 40, height: 40)
}

let stack = UIStackView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 40))
stack.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

stack.addArrangedSubview(views[0])
stack.addArrangedSubview(views[1])
stack.addArrangedSubview(views[2])

stack.axis = .Horizontal
stack.alignment = .Fill
stack.distribution = .FillEqually
stack.spacing = 5

rootView.addSubview(stack)
```