# Programmatically adding views to a UIStackView

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uistackview

I am attempting to add two dynamic `UILabels` to a `UIStackLabel`. The goal is center the two labels horizontally in the middle of the view.

The two `UILabels` are:

```
var nameLabel: UILabel!
var ageLabel: UILabel!
```

And the `UIStackView` is:

```
var stackedInfoView: UIStackView!
```

I have attempted to follow the guidelines provided in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30728062/add-views-in-uistackview-programmatically), configuring my views as such:

```
nameLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 120.0, height: 24.0))
ageLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 80.0, height: 24.0))
nameLabel.text = "Harry Potter"
ageLabel.text = "100"


stackedInfoView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [nameLabel, ageLabel])
stackedInfoView.axis = .horizontal
stackedInfoView.distribution = .equalSpacing
stackedInfoView.alignment = .center
stackedInfoView.spacing = 30.0
stackedInfoView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.extendedNavView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
stackedInfoView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.extendedNavView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

self.extendedNavView.addSubview(stackedInfoView) //extendedNavView is configured inside Storyboard
```

My issue is that, `stackedInfoView` will not show up. Furthermore, when I print its `frame`, I get `{{0, 0}, {0, 0}}`. I also get a bunch of error messages about `Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.`

What am I doing incorrectly in making my `UIStackView`? Any guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two problems,

```
stackedInfoView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.extendedNavView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
stackedInfoView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.extendedNavView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

should be put after `self.extendedNavView.addSubview(stackedInfoView)`. Because the stack view must be in the view hierarchy before configure the constraints.

Second, add `stackedInfoView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` to tell UIKit you want to use auto layout to set the position of the stack view.

The following code should work if `extendedNavView` has no layout issue in the storyboard:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var nameLabel: UILabel!
    var ageLabel: UILabel!

    var stackedInfoView: UIStackView!

    nameLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 120.0, height: 24.0))
    ageLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 80.0, height: 24.0))
    nameLabel.text = "Harry Potter"
    ageLabel.text = "100"

    stackedInfoView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [nameLabel, ageLabel])
    stackedInfoView.axis = .horizontal
    stackedInfoView.distribution = .equalSpacing
    stackedInfoView.alignment = .center
    stackedInfoView.spacing = 30.0

    stackedInfoView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    self.extendedNavView.addSubview(stackedInfoView) //extendedNavView is configured inside Storyboard

    stackedInfoView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.extendedNavView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    stackedInfoView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.extendedNavView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

}
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot