# Method passed to UIButton#addTarget not called

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I'm going through [Apple's iOS development with Swift tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ImplementingACustomControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH19-SW1) and have gotten myself stuck on the 5th stage:

```
import UIKit

class RatingControl: UIStackView {

    // MARK: Initialisation
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        setupButtons()
    }

    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)

        setupButtons()
    }

    // MARK: Button action
    @objc func ratingButtonTapped(button: UIButton) {
        NSLog("Button pressed")
    }

    // MARK: Private methods
    private func setupButtons() {
        NSLog("setupButtons() called")

        // Create the button
        let button = UIButton()
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

        // Add constraints
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44.0).isActive = true
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44.0).isActive = true

        // Setup the button action
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(RatingControl.ratingButtonTapped(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        // Add the button to the stack
        addArrangedSubview(button)
    }
}
```

`setupButtons` is called and I see the message in Xcode's debug console, and the button appears as a red box on the simulator: [image: iPhone 8 simulator]

However, when I click on the button, nothing happens - no message is printed to the debug console.

I honestly have no clue how I would even begin debugging this, since everything compiles/runs without errors, and I've already tried placing debug messages around what seems to be the issue.

Does anyone have any ideas on what's going on?

EDIT: Here is where the class is being used, and the output in the console:
[image: xcode screenshot]

Comment: `ratingButtonTapped` method is in the same class??

Comment: Yes, both are in the `RatingControl` class

Comment: I updated the question to add the full class code

Comment: WFM in an Xcode 9 playground, is it possible that the stack view itself or any view on top of it has `isUserInteractionEnabled`  set to `false`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tested your code in Playgrounds, and it works as expected. Therefore I expect that you are using the `RatingControl` incorrectly. One possible bug might be that one of its superviews has `isUserInteractionEnabled` set to `false`. Check this example:

```
// A UIKit based Playground for presenting user interface
import PlaygroundSupport
import UIKit

class RatingControl: UIStackView {

    // MARK: Initialisation
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupButtons()
    }

    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setupButtons()
    }

    // MARK: Button action
    @objc func ratingButtonTapped(button: UIButton) {
        print("Button pressed")
    }

    // MARK: Private methods
    private func setupButtons() {
        print("setupButtons() called")

        // Create the button
        let button = UIButton()
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

        // Add constraints
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44.0).isActive = true
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44.0).isActive = true

        // Setup the button action
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(RatingControl.ratingButtonTapped(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        // Add the button to the stack
        addArrangedSubview(button)
    }
}

class A: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.addSubview(RatingControl(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40)))
        // if you uncomment the following line, the button will stop working
//        self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    }
}

// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = A()
```

If that's not the case, include the code in which you use the `RatingControl`, because that's where the bug lies.

Comment: I use RatingControl from Main.storyboard as the class of a stack view. Everything in the view seems pretty simple so I don't think anything is overlaying it...

I added a screenshot in the question

Comment: @konsolas it's not about overlaying views, but about superviews.. if you put `RatingControl` as a subview to another `stackView`, and that `stackView` has `isUserInteractionEnabled` set to false, the buttons won't get touch events.. same applies to the `RatingControl` itself - make sure that `RatingControl` has `isUserInteractionEnabled` checked

Comment: I rechecked the storyboard and it looks like I had a random stack view around it that wasn't doing anything - the button works after I removed it.

Comment: superview isUserInteractionEnabled was false in my case, thanks for your suggestion @MilanNosáľ.

Answer (score 0):

It's working normally with me, I've put  `self.view.addSubview(button)`
instead of  `addArrangedSubview(button)` .

Comment: That doesn't seem possible for me - the view property doesn't exist in UIStackView

Comment: True, but that should give you a clue why your code isn't working. I see that you're adding arranged subview but to nothing. Maybe you should use yourStackViewName.addArrangedSubview(button) ? Check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30728062/add-views-in-uistackview-programmatically