# Setting CollectionView cell height based on number of buttons

Tags: ios, swift, dynamic, uicollectionview

I have a collection view that will have a `UILabel` and between 2-5 `UIButton`s.

I want the cell to size to how many buttons that are visible according to each cell. I know that each button is about a 100 in height.

```
class myViewController: UIViewController {

    var myCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 100, right: 0) // add spacing to the bottom
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: 300)
        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 20
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 20

        myCollectionView=UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height), collectionViewLayout: layout)
        myCollectionView.delegate=self
        myCollectionView.dataSource=self
        myCollectionView.register(MyCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        myCollectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = false
        myCollectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        myCollectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
        myCollectionView.backgroundColor=UIColor.white
        myCollectionView.isPagingEnabled = false

        loadViews()
    }

    func loadViews() {
        self.view.addSubview(myCollectionView)
        myCollectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive=true
        myCollectionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor).isActive=true
        myCollectionView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor).isActive=true
        myCollectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive=true

    }

}
```

Note that the above code block has `layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: 300)` which works great for 3 buttons (3*100 = 300).

Then when setting up my cell class I create my buttons and then determine their visibility based off of a variable (at the bottom of this).

```
class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var btn1: UIButton!
    var btn2: UIButton!
    var btn3: UIButton!
    var btn4: UIButton!
    var btn5: UIButton!

   override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        setupViews()
    }

    func setupViews() {

        addSubview(lblQue)
        lblQue.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 30).isActive=true
        lblQue.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 12).isActive=true
        lblQue.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: -12).isActive=true
        lblQue.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive=true

        let btnWidth: CGFloat = 650
        let btnHeight: CGFloat = 65
        btn1 = getButton(tag: 0)
        addSubview(btn1)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([btn1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lblQue.bottomAnchor, constant: 10), btn1.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor, constant: -300), btn1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: btnWidth), btn1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: btnHeight)])
        btn1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnOptionAction), for: .touchUpInside)

        btn2 = getButton(tag: 1)
        addSubview(btn2)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([btn2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btn1.bottomAnchor, constant: 10), btn2.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor, constant: -300), btn2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: btnWidth), btn2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: btnHeight)])
        btn2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnOptionAction), for: .touchUpInside)

        btn3 = getButton(tag: 2)
        addSubview(btn3)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([btn3.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btn2.bottomAnchor, constant: 10), btn3.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor, constant: -300), btn3.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: btnWidth), btn3.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: btnHeight)])
        btn3.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnOptionAction), for: .touchUpInside)

        btn4 = getButton(tag: 3)
        addSubview(btn4)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([btn4.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btn3.bottomAnchor, constant: 10), btn4.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor, constant: -300), btn4.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: btnWidth), btn4.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: btnHeight)])
        btn4.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnOptionAction), for: .touchUpInside)

        btn5 = getButton(tag: 4)
        addSubview(btn5)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([btn5.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btn4.bottomAnchor, constant: 10), btn5.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor, constant: -300), btn5.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: btnWidth), btn5.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: btnHeight)])
        btn5.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnOptionAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    func getButton(tag: Int) -> UIButton {
        let btn=UIButton()
        btn.tag=tag
        btn.setTitle("Option", for: .normal)
        btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
        btn.backgroundColor=UIColor.white
        btn.layer.borderWidth=1
        btn.layer.borderColor=UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        btn.layer.cornerRadius=5
        btn.clipsToBounds=true
        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
        return btn
    }

    let lblQue: UILabel = {
        let lbl=UILabel()
        lbl.text="This is a question and you have to answer it?"
        lbl.textColor=UIColor.black
        lbl.textAlignment = .center
        lbl.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
        lbl.numberOfLines=4
        lbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
        return lbl
    }()

    var myVariable: MyClassIMade? {
        didSet {
             // go through and determine button Text and Visibility of each button
             // i.e. 
             // if 1>0 { 
             //     btn3.visible = false
             // } else {
             //     btn3.visible = true
             // }

        }
    }
```

So how can I determine how many buttons are visible to determine my size of cell for each section?

Comment: Better to embed your buttons in a stack view.

Comment: @teja_D and then it will figure out the height itself? Do you know of an example/tutorial that talks about this?

Comment: Refer this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30728062/add-views-in-uistackview-programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I ended up solving it:

I used [sizeForItemAt](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout/1617708-collectionview?language=objc) which overrides all else and allowed me to get my cell for each row/usecase.

Basically, I can access all of the controls tied to my cell and determine their visibility and alter the height according to that.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! QuizCollectionViewCell

    var countOfButtonsNotHidden = 0

    if !cell.btn1.isHidden {
        countOfButtonsNotHidden += 1
    }
    if !cell.btn2.isHidden {
        countOfButtonsNotHidden += 1
    }
    if !cell.btn3.isHidden {
        countOfButtonsNotHidden += 1
    }
    if !cell.btn4.isHidden {
        countOfButtonsNotHidden += 1
    }
    if !cell.btn5.isHidden {
        countOfButtonsNotHidden += 1
    }

    return CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: CGFloat(countOfButtonsNotHidden * 100))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this ? just get all the buttons inside an array and then loop through them to check which button are hidden and which are not. you could use 
`.isHidden` to hide and display them and then check which is hidden and return the number..

Example function :

```
func getButtonsCount(buttons: [UIButton]) -> Int{
    //A counter to get how many button are not hidden
    var count = Int()
    //A Loop to check which buttons are hidden and increment the counter
    for button in buttons {
        if button.isHidden == true {
            count += 1
        }
    }

    return count
}
```

Comment: There is no point to count as you can see total of 5 `UIButton`'s in the file.

Comment: Hi @yasser, how would I set that with my layout though? I do set .isHidden = true on some buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `UIStackView` to layout your buttons. When you set the buttons to `.isHidden` the stack view will automatically deal with the layout of the buttons.

Example:

```
let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [button1, button2, button3, button4, button5])
stackView.axis = .vertical
stackView.alignment = .fill
stackView.distribution = .equalSpacing
stackView.spacing = 10
```

Next, you can calculate the height of the collection view cell by multiplying the number of visible buttons with your set button height.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "YourCellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! YourCellClass

    let buttonHeight: CGFloat = 45
    let numberOfVisibleButtons = 0

    if !cell.button1.isHidden { numberOfVisibleButtons += 1 }
    if !cell.button2.isHidden { numberOfVisibleButtons += 1 }
    if !cell.button3.isHidden { numberOfVisibleButtons += 1 }
    if !cell.button4.isHidden { numberOfVisibleButtons += 1 }
    if !cell.button5.isHidden { numberOfVisibleButtons += 1 }

    let cellHeight: CGFloat = (buttonHeight + cell.stackView.spacing) * numberOfVisibleButtons

    return CGSize(width: yourCellWidth, height: cellHeight)

}
```