# Adding images to table view cell problem using stack views

Tags: swift, uitableview, uistackview

in my prototype cell I have a horizontal stack view and I connected that to my UITableViewCell and I defined an update function In my UITableViewCell that adds multiple images to the stack view and I called the function In TableViewController cellForRowAt but nothing nothing happens.

```
//inside UITableViewCell  
@IBOutlet weak var lineStack: UIStackView!

func update(_ imageName: String){
    let numberOfCopies = Int(deviceWidth/50)
    let startX = (Int(deviceWidth) - (numberOfCopies*50))/2
    xValue = xValue + startX
    let image = UIImage(named: imageName)

    for _ in 1...Int(numberOfCopies) {
        xValue = xValue + heightValue
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xValue , y: 0, width: widthValue, height: heightValue)
        lineStack.addSubview(imageView)
    }
}

 //inside TableViewController

 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Line", for: indexPath) as! LineTableViewCell
        let imageName = imagesName[indexPath.row]
        cell.update(imageName)
        return cell
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your post indicates you want your images to be `50 x 50` points... use auto-layout constraints with `.addArrangedSubview()`:

```
class TestCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var lineStack: UIStackView!

    func update(_ imageName: String) {
        let numberOfCopies = Int(deviceWidth/50)
        let image = UIImage(named: imageName)

        for _ in 1...Int(numberOfCopies) {
            let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
            imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
            imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
            lineStack.addArrangedSubview(imageView)
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT** Sample result, with stack view centered horizontally:

[image]

Stack view is set to:

```
Axis: Horizontal
Alignment: Fill
Distribution: Fill
Spacing: 0
```

and this is the layout with constraints:

[image]

Note that the stack view has a Width constraint of `10`, but its Priority is `250` ... that allows the stack view to stretch horizontally, while keeping IB satisfied with the constraints.

Comment: Thanks a lot how can you do something to bring all the images in you're sample result to center and stick them to the bottom of the table view. and if you can tell me how you constrainted your stack view in your storyboard. 

Comment: Added screen-caps with the stack view centered horizontally, along with the constraints setup. Don't know what you mean by *"stick them to the bottom of the table view"*

Answer (score 0):

For the line:

> lineStack.addSubview(imageView)

Instead of `addSubview()` you need to do it with `addArrangedSubview()`. The former is the regular way of adding a subview to a view, whereas the latter is specifically for `UIStackView` and tells the view to insert it properly.

Comment: width and height for imageView frame are equal to 50 when I use addArrangedSubview it adds Huge images to the stack view

Comment: take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30728062/add-views-in-uistackview-programmatically maybe it helps